# Two column grid how to prevent overlapping

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've started a new layout like shown below, but if I start resizing the browser, the content in the "right" column, will overflow into the left column, at least until the "break" is hit and bootstrap starts stacking the items.

How can I control this overflow problem?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-bottom:5px">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">a</div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">b</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[ update ] 
I think my issue was related to the min-width attribute Im running into with the different col-* classes. Once I defined some values for these, I can control where the "breaking" occurs.

Comment: Your divs should also have `col-12` I think.

Comment: Do you have a snippet/fiddle that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to keep this layout?

I feel you have a useless column with a a row (which itself contains two columns inside)

You could simplify your layout and simply have a container with row(s) - and then each row will have the necessary columns.

Sort of like this:

(added the green border CSS for illustration purposes only - remove as necessary)

```css
div.col-sm-6{
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-bottom:5px">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">a</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">b</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Bootstrap you work with rows first...then everything inside is a column...so remove your col-sm-12 div...

Every row will span the full 12 width unless you break it up like you specified into 2 smaller 6 sections...

Since they are equal you don't need to specify a break point for it...just class col will do...

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">a</div>
      <div class="col">b</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but in retrospect, I think my real issue was with the min-width attribute effect that comes into effect